# C/C++ library for solving nonlinear systems of equations

Tags: library, c++, math

My system of equations is like this:

> (x - a<sub>1</sub>)<sup>2</sup> + (y - b<sub>1</sub>)<sup>2</sup> = c<sub>1</sub>
>
> (x - a<sub>2</sub>)<sup>2</sup> + (y - b<sub>2</sub>)<sup>2</sup> = c<sub>2</sub>

I know it is simple using matlab:

```
solve((x-a1)^2 + (y-b1)^2 - c1, (x-a2)^2 + (y-b2)^2 - c2)
```

But how to solve this problem using C/C++? I know a math library called `lapack`, but is for linear equation. Any suggestions?

Comment: I wrote one implementation of Newton-Raphson method, see here for details:  https://dilawarnotes.wordpress.com/2016/04/14/multi-dimentional-root-fiding-using-newton-raphson-method/  . It is not well tested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Reference: [What good libraries are there for solving a system of non-linear equations in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233964/what-good-libraries-are-there-for-solving-a-system-of-non-linear-equations-in-c)

I'm assuming you mean free software. Referencing the above stackoverflow question, you could use:

1. Sundials: https://computation.llnl.gov/casc/sundials/main.html
2. GNU:
   http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Multidimensional-Root_002dFinding.html#index-nonlinear-systems-of-equations_002c-solution-of-2426

The rest of them that are listed on the referenced stackoverflow question are Fortran based. You can only use them if you use [f2c](http://www.netlib.org/f2c/) (Fortran to C program)

Answer (score 1):

I would like suggest few answers I found from the web after doing a bit of search.but Its always the fact that library depends upon your individual needs :)

- [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) 
  *Eigen is a C++ template library for linear algebra: matrices, vectors, numerical solvers, and related algorithms.*
          *It supports all matrix sizes, from small fixed-size matrices to arbitrarily large dense matrices, and even sparse matrices.and supports all standard numeric types, including std::complex, integers, and is easily extensible to custom numeric types.various matrix decompositions and geometry features.Its ecosystem of unsupported modules provides many specialized features such as non-linear optimization, matrix functions, a polynomial solver, FFT, and much more.*
- [Trilinos](http://trilinos.org/) *It provides a lot of classes and functions to manage
  vectors and matrices in parallel, to solve linear and non-linear
  systems, to solve ordinary differential equations and calculate
  eigenvalues, etc*.
- [ALIAS-C++](https://www-sop.inria.fr/coprin/logiciels/ALIAS/ALIAS-C++/ALIAS-C++.html) *A C++ Algorithms Library of Interval Analysis for equation Systems for Solving systems with linear and non-linear terms*
- [MINPACK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MINPACK) *It is a library of FORTRAN subroutines for the solving of systems of nonlinear equations, or the least squares minimization of the residual of a set of linear or nonlinear equations.*

Source : [List of numerical libraries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_numerical_libraries)

Answer (score 0):

consider omnn::math https://github.com/ohhmm/openmind/blob/master/omnn/math/test/08_System.cpp

```
    Valuable a1, a2, b1, b2; // init with values

    System sys;
    Variable x,y;
    sys << (x-a1)^2 + (y-b1)^2 - c1; // addin an equation as an equality to 0
    sys << (x-a2)^2 + (y-b2)^2 - c2;

    for(auto& solution : sys.Solve(x))
            std::cout << solution;
```

alternative way is to make single equation:

((x-a1)^2 + (y-b1)^2 - c1)^2 + ((x-a2)^2 + (y-b2)^2 - c2)^2 = 0

```
Variable x,y;
Valuable a1, a2, b1, b2; // init with values
auto eq = ((x-a1)^2 + (y-b1)^2 - c1)^2 + ((x-a2)^2 + (y-b2)^2 - c2)^2;
eq.SetView(Valuable::View::Equation);  // optional: equation optimizations
// get y function:
auto fn = eq(y);

// show
std::cout << fn << std::endl;

// evaluate
auto evaluate = fn;
evaluate.eval(x, 10);
evaluate.optimize(); // calculate
// show calculated value at x=10:
std::cout << evaluate << std::endl;
```

Here is the sample CMake project: https://github.com/ohhmm/NonLinearSystem

Comment: do you have a Linux version? Just wanna quickly test your codes. No windows here:(

Comment: Yes, it is crossplatform with cmake. If you face difficulties with compiling then try to set clang compiler while configuring. Fill free to send pull requests. Current dev branch is 'ts'.

Comment: @math101, https://www.deduction-fw.org/

Comment: do I really need clang? I think clang is mostly for mac users. I use VS codes and ::codeblock for cpp on linux...dunt think i have a clang compiler here:(

Comment: im on ubuntu 20.04. Perhaps i should get clang-9?

Comment: It is currently buildable with GCC on Ubuntu 20.04